# I can't configure how high the character jumps. (unity 2d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've got a script from a tutorial that makes my player jump when you press a button but I don't know how to configure how high it jumps. Heres the code:

```
var before : Sprite;
var after : Sprite;
var isGrounded : boolean;
var Animator : Animator;
var character : GameObject;
var jump : float = 0;
var jumpSpeed : float = 5;
var jumpTimer : float = 0;

function Start () {
    isGrounded = true;  
}

function Update () {
    Animator.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
    if(jump == 1) {
        jumpTimer = jumpTimer + 1;
    }
    if(jumpTimer >= 50) {
        jumpTimer = 0;
        jump = 0;
    } 
}

function OnMouseDown () {
    isGrounded = false;
    GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = after;
    if(jump == 0) {
        character.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y = jumpSpeed;
        jump = 1;
    }
    yield WaitForSeconds (0.5);
    isGrounded = true;
}

function OnMouseUp () {
   GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = before;    
}
```

I tried lowering the floats for jump/jumpspeed/jumptimer but it just won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: character.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y = jumpSpeed; is the line that changes the players y velocity (jumps)... You will need to lower the "jumpSpeed" value in order to make its jump smaller. P.S make sure you change the value in the inspector as opposed to in the script because the inspector overrides the script value.

Answer (score 2):

Placing my comment into an answer for anyone else using the same tutorial and having the same issue.

The line below is used to alter the players y velocity.

```
character.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D).velocity.y = jumpSpeed;
```

In order to change the jump height of the player, you will need to alter the `jumpSpeed` variable.

**Note**
If you are altering the `jumpSpeed` variable at the top of the script and it isn't changing, it is because the value in the inspector overrides the value entered at the top of the script.